# ¿Cómo buscar en las columnas de un array en Python?, ¿por qué me da error?

Tags: python, array, pandas, numpy

Tengo el siguiente array:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejecuto el siguiente comando con error, y no se por qué.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué quieres hacer exactamente?, ¿Qué datos quieres seleccionar de tu dataset?

Comment: Para seleccionar una columna: ```nombre_dataframe ["nombre_columna"]```

Answer (score 1):

A ver si te entiendo.

Para seleccionar las columnas desde la 1 hasta la 6 de tu DataFrame, que según veo en tu imagen es lo que quieres hacer, puedes usar `.loc[filas, columnas]` para accesar los datos, te dejo un ejemplo dummy para que observes la forma correcta de hacerlo:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(pd.Series(list('abcdefghij'))) # Armo un dataframe de juguete
```

Output:

```
a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

Ahora, lo que haras será esto:

```
df_output = df.loc[:, 'a':'f'] # Selecciono las columnas desde la "a" hasta la "f", con todas sus filas.
```

Output:

```
a   b   c   d   e   f
0   1   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   1   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   1   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   1   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   1   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   1
6   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0
8   0   0   0   0   0   0
9   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Te dejo [la documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc#pandas.DataFrame.loc), por si quieres profundizar mas al respecto.

Comment: Gracias. Se nota estoy empezando en Python eh?. Tienes razón. Creo que intentaba  hacerlo como si fuese un array y no un dataframe. Gracias

Comment: De nada @DANIEL todos empezamos algún día en este mundo con Python. si la respuesta ha sido de ayuda, te agradecería que la marcaras como respuesta Correcta, con el símbolo  ✔ al final de la pregunta. Así, esta pregunta puede llegar a más personas que tengan la misma duda. Saludos :)